# How to set a pixel in a Slick2D Texture to a specific ARGB Int

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, slick2d

I need a way to change a pixel, or a group of pixels to a specific color in a Slick2D Texture.
I have the file loaded and everything, I just need a way to set a pixel a Color.
Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean with Slick2D texture? Texture is an interface, what implementation are you using?

Comment: "import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;"

Comment: Thats the interface, I asked what implementation you are using... you cannot use that interface for that, you need an implementation of the `Texture` interface.